# The method getString(String) is undefined for the type String in Android

Tags: java, android, android-activity, parse-platform

I am trying to push url using Parse.com and i added a code in which get String is showing error. Can anyone help me out please!

Help me out Please! Getting an Error

> The method getString(String) is undefined for the type String**

```
    package com.example.pushnotificationdemo;



import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.example.pushnotificationdemo.R;
import com.parse.ParseAnalytics;
import com.parse.ParseInstallation;
import com.parse.PushService;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;



public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    WebView webframe;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        String jsonData = extras.getString("com.parse.Data");
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonData);
        String pushStore = json.getString("data");
        if(pushStore!=null) {
            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(pushStore.getString("url")));
          startActivity(browserIntent);
        } 

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(getIntent());

        PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MainActivity.class);
        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();



        /** Cerco l'elemento in /res/layout/main.xml */
        webframe = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

        /** Javascript abilitato (ma non flash) */
        webframe.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);



        /** Simulo il webbrowser chrome di android*/
        webframe.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()); 
        webframe.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()); 

        /** Assegno l'url di apertura del webframe */
        webframe.loadUrl("http://www.dlybugs.com");






    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please post the full stack trace of the error, so we know what line the error is being thrown against.

Comment: Yeah, Post the logcat report.

Comment: **pushStore.**getString**("url"))**, what is it ?

Comment: The method getString(String) is undefined for the type String                                            (1 fix found ) change to 'substring(...)'

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error from this code:

```
pushStore.getString("url")
```

because `pushStore` is a `String`. It's not a `JSONObject` that you can call `getString` on. You probably want this code instead:

```
String pushStore = json.getString("data.url");
if(pushStore!=null) {
    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(pushStore));
    startActivity(browserIntent);
}
```